# .htaccess dynamic imageurl rewrite

Tags: image, apache, .htaccess, dynamic, redirect

I want to redirect all my product images to an external site using htaccess.
However I cant figure out how to use dynamic variables, the image-url looks like this:

httpz://localhost/oc1505/image/80x80-10035.jpg

Where 80x80 is the height and the width, and the 10035.jpg is the link to the external image.
So in this case I would like to redirect it to an url that looks like:

httpz://www.othersite.nl/imgs/prd/**kln**/10035.jpg

how ever if the source image is 150x150-10035.jpg it should redirect to.

httpz://www.othersite.nl/imgs/prd/**std**/10035.jpg

And I have a few other formats that I would like to redirect.

If someone could help me out a little I would be very happy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule 80X80-(.*)$ https://www.othersite.nl/imgs/prd/kln/$1
RewriteRule 150x150-(.*)$ https://www.othersite.nl/imgs/prd/std/$1
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot! I was making it too complicated for myself.